# space invaders game drawing but not updating

Tags: java

Making space invaders in java through android studio, when i run the app, it loads up, everything on screen but nothing updates. There are no code errors as far as I can see & It registers clicks in the logcat of AS. Any ideas? Thanks

This is the update method code in the main game class:

```
private void update(){

        spaceShip.update(fps);
        if(bullet.getStatus()){
            bullet.update(fps);
        }
        if(bullet2.getStatus()){
            bullet2.update(fps);
        }
        if(mine.getStatus()){
            mine.update(fps);
        }

        if(redenemy.getVisibility()){
            redenemy.update(fps);
        }
        checkCollisions();
        if(redenemy.getVisibility()) {
            redEnemyShoot();
        }
        boolean touch_side = false;
        //loops through the array of invaders updating their positions
        for(int i = 0; i < numInvaders; i++){
        if(Invaders[i].getVisibility()){
            Invaders[i].update(fps);
        }
        //check if an invader touches the side, if so set to true
        if(Invaders[i].getX() > screenX - Invaders[i].getLength() || Invaders[i].getX() < 0) 
        {
            touch_side = true;
        }
```

there is also a run method:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        while (playing) {
            // Capture the current time in milliseconds in startFrameTime
            long startFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // Update the frame
            if(!paused){
                update();
            }

            // Draw the frame
            draw();


            long timeThis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

            timeThisFrame = System.currentTimeMillis() - startFrameTime;
            if (timeThisFrame >= 1) {
                fps = 1000 / timeThisFrame;
            }

        }

    }
```

Everything is drawn to the screen, just nothing updates. If you also require the alien enemy class, let me know. I'm relatively new to java so I apologise for the state of the code and question, just need some help.

Comment: Might be an obvious one, but have you checked if `paused` is set correctly?

Comment: Is this code run on a separate thread than your main thread? If not then the UI may just be locking up due to your code being stuck in an endless loop and there never being time for the UI to update. If you do not know how threads work, then the best place to start is the official tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Sorry guys. It's such a silly issue, the code actually works fine, my laptop's ram was spiking to 98% usage due to AS emulator and the game was basically freezing in every frame and eventaully crashing. Apologies, simple fix - run it on my android device with debug mode! Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Ah yes, the perfectly good working emulator :D. Good luck with your progress!